# Скрипт не открывается с кнопки при выпуске в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, bash

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QPprocess process1;
    QString exe = "xterm";
    QStringList params;
    params << "-e" << "skript.sh";
    process1.start(exe, params);
    process1.waitForFinished();
    qDebug() << process1.readAllStandardOutput(); 
}
```

При отладке скрипт запускается и работает
При выпуске скрипт не открывается и не выполняется

Comment: Скрипт в другую папку переложите

Comment: @gbg Не помогает

Comment: @gbg в какую папку?

Comment: В папку сборки. В release полагаю

Comment: @vegorov это не помогает

Comment: @vegorov я привел код

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь к скрипту.

Answer (score 1):

Была подобная проблема. Указал полный путь к скрипту:

```
params << "/full-path/skript.sh";
```

и все заработало.