# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью кнопки в Qt открывать скрипты для их дальнейшего выполнения?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, bash

Нужно открыть скрипт по нажатию кнопки, чтобы все команды начали выполнение.

Comment: @vegorov нам нужно запустить скрипт с помощью кнопки

Comment: @vegorov при отладке скрипт запускается, а при выпуске не работает

Comment: Омг. Да вам же уже ответили в прошлом вашем Вопросе. Удаляйте этот

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Скрипт не открывается с кнопки при выпуске в Qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999376/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-qt)